# Large table in table cell invoke page break

Tags: java, itext

I have single PdfPTable with single column. One page fit 50 rows. If I add some text data to table (for an example, 300 rows), report work fine. When I add a PdfPTable into cell (for example, 20 string cells, PdfPTable(with 20 rows in it or less), and 270 string cells), all work fine too:

```
/--------
20 string rows
inner table (20 rows)
10 string rows
/-------
...additional rows
```

But, when my inner table have more rows (mainTable[20 string rows, innerTable[90 string rows], 270 string rows], report break first page, and start innerTable output on the second page.

```
/---------
20 string rows
whitespace for 30 rows
/---------
inner table (50 rows from 90)
/---------
inner table (40 rows from 90)
..additional data
```

And I need this:

```
/---------
20 string rows
inner table (30 rows from 90)
/---------
inner table (50 rows from 90)
/---------
inner table (10 rows from 80)
..additional data
```

Anybody know solution?

ps itext version - 2.1.7

Comment: There is no solution for iText 2.1.7. That version dates from July 2009. We are not going to spend any time on that version, knowing that we've fixed many bugs in the last 5 to 6 years. Also: please read the legal section in the free ebook [The Best Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) and you'll understand why there will be very little response to your question.

Comment: Hm. Sad. By the way, I try to do this code with IText 5.5, but result was the same. Is there any solutions?

Comment: For somebody to be able to help you, one must first understand the question. Right now, the question reads as: I don't understand the difference between `setSplitLate(true)` and `setSplitLate(false)`. You should sow some code and some images. Right now, it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. If people have to spend 15 minutes before they can understand your question, they may not have an extra 15 minutes to answer it. (As for me: you mentioning iText 2.1.7 was sufficient to destroy all goodwill.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [NestedTables2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/NestedTables2) example. In this example, we tell iText that it's OK to split cells as soon as a row doesn't fit on a page:

[image]

This is not the default: by default, iText will try to keep a row intact by forwarding it to the next page. Only if the row doesn't fit the page, the row will be split.

Changing the default involves adding a single line to your code. That line is called: `table.setSplitLate(false);`

This is the full method that created the PDF shown in the screen shot:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setSplitLate(false);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 15});
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        table.addCell(String.valueOf(i));
        table.addCell("It is not smart to use iText 2.1.7!");
    }
    PdfPTable innertable = new PdfPTable(2);
    innertable.setWidths(new int[]{1, 15});
    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        innertable.addCell(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        innertable.addCell("Upgrade if you're a professional developer!");
    }
    table.addCell("21");
    table.addCell(innertable);
    for (int i = 22; i <= 40; i++) {
        table.addCell(String.valueOf(i));
        table.addCell("It is not smart to use iText 2.1.7!");
    }
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

Note that you should not use iText 2.1.7. If you do, you could have a problem with your employer, customer, investor. Read more about this in the legal section of the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html)