# itextsharp leaving first page empty and printing table conent in following table

Tags: asp.net, itext, pdf-generation

I have three part in my PDF generating document using iTextSharp library.

The Header and footer I am printing using OnEndPage() of PdfPageEventHelper class. The header and footer printing well in all pages.But problem in printing large table content from middle of the page.

Now, I am facing problem when I have more that 100 table rows content to print on middle of the page.

On first page (middle of the page) I am printing table with more than 100 rows, but in this case it leave the first page empty and start printing table content on second page. Here is my table that I am trying to print on first page

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
table.HeaderRows = 1;

table.SplitLate = false;
table.SplitRows = false;
table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 100, 75, 75, 75, 75 });
table.LockedWidth = true;

for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new phrase());
            cell.Colspan = 5;
            table.AddCell(cell);
        }
```

I am using iTextSharp version: 5.4.5.0

Is there any configuration need to do, that will prevent page break?

[image: Expected result. Image-1]

But I am getting actual result in this format

[image: Actual result format, Image-2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large table in table cell invoke page break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503491/large-table-in-table-cell-invoke-page-break)

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to comment on these two lines:

```
table.SplitLate = false;
table.SplitRows = false;
```

The first line tells iTextSharp what it should do if a row doesn't fit a page. If you set this value to `false`, rows will be split *late*. For instance: you have a big row that doesn't fit the current page. In that case, the row will be forwarded to the next page. If it still doesn't fit the page, then another decision needs to be made: should the row be split or not?

The second line gives iTextSharp the answer to that question. If the value of `SplitRows` is `true`, then the row will be split. If the value is `false`, the row will be dropped. Allow me to quote the official documentation (p115 of "iText in Action - Second Edition"):

> Ths is a dangerous line, because now *not one row* will be split. Rows that are too high to fit on a page will be *dropped from the table!*

I have the feeling that you want all the rows to show up in the table, so I suggest that you change the two lines I mentioned to:

```
table.SplitLate = true;
table.SplitRows = true;
```

Actually: why don't you just remove those two lines? The default value of `SplitLate` and of `SplitRows` is `true`.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have tried with these two option also, but still it not work. 
table.SplitLate = true;
table.SplitRows = true;
Actually I am rendering this table in middle of the first page, but it breaking that half page and starting from second page.How to avoid such problem ?

Comment: You need to clarify that part of your question: *Actually I am rendering this table in middle of the first page, but it breaking that half page and starting from second page.* I have no idea what you mean by that. How are you rendering this table in the middle of the first page? What do you mean when you say "it breaking"? Accurate English would be very helpful here. If that's a problem: show some more code and show what the result looks like.

Comment: I mean to say that I am printing table in middle of the page, and the table have more than 100 rows. So in this case the whole table is breaking from that middle of page and start printing on new page. So how avoid such problem ? I want to start printing of that table from middle of page and whatever rows left, that should print on another page. Now hope you better understand my problem.

Comment: @Herin No, I don't understand the problem. I can perfectly start a table halfway the page, have all the rows that fit on the first page, and then have the rest of the rows on the following pages. In other words: I can't reproduce your problem. As far as I'm concerned: a problem that can't be reproduced, isn't a problem. You should document your question: which version of iTextSharp are you using? How are you adding the table halfway the page? Are you adding empty lines with `document.Add()`? Are you using `ColumnText`? Please clarify!

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have edited my question, added two images. First one is for expected result, and second one is for Actual result.
I have problem with child table which is printing from half page, whole table gets printed on new page.

Comment: Your question is very misleading because your tiny code sample shows an ordinary table whereas your problem is related to *nested tables*. Once again: which version of iTextSharp are you using (older versions aren't that friendly towards nested tables) and what does your *nested table* code look like?

Comment: I am using iTextSharp version : 5.4.5.0
My Nested table will display list of more than 100 records.
So nested table is just a for loop which will print more than 100 records, and then I will assign this nested table into parent table.

Comment: Do you have `SplitLate = true` for both tables? Also iTextSharp 5.4.5 dates from December 2013. that's more than 2 years ago. Maybe the problem has been fixed by now (if there is actually a problem).

Comment: If have voted to close this question as duplicate because it has been answered before: [How to invoke a page break for nested tables?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-invoke-page-break-nested-tables). The screen shot in that answer clearly shows that the nested tables isn't forwarded to the next page. The OP refuses to share his code. If he did, we'd notice wrong use of the `SplitLate` property.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me using nested tables.
I solved this problem using `.SplitLate = false;` in the first table :)