# Is there a way to tell iText 5 to allow page break in the middle of a table cell?

Tags: itext

We are using iText 5.13. I am creating a form document using a series of tables, each with a single column, to place one after the other to create the form boxes. In these cells are varying sizes of Paragraphs. When viewing the PDF, if the next table won't fit on the page, we have a large blank space on the bottom half of the page, and the table starts on the next page. If the cell is large enough such that it won't fit on one page, the engine will allow it to page break in the middle of the cell, which is exactly what I want for the cells to do all the time, not just when there is a large cell. I have tried setting `table.keepTogether(false)`, but does not help.

Here is snapshot of the page break occurring too soon at the end of a table, when the next table is too big to fit on the rest of the page
[image: Here is snapshot of the page break occurring too soon at the end of a table, when the next table is too big to fit on the rest of the page]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution over at iText KB:  `table.setSplitLate(false);` [answer](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/faq/how-to-invoke-a-page-break-for-nested-tables)

Comment: that itext kb article in turn actually refers to [this old stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28517802/1729265).